# If Then statement displays all possibilites

Tags: calculator, ti-basic

I'm trying to display text based on a user's input. For example inputting the word `APPLE` should make it display BANANA.

This snippet works fine:

```
:Input X
:If X=APPLE
:Disp "BANANA"
```

But I'm unsure how to build off this to make a series of checks:

```
:Input X
:If X=Apple
:Disp "BANANA"
:If X=LEMON
:Disp "LIME"
:If X=PEACH
:Disp "PEAR"
```

If I do this, it displays BANANA, LIME, and PEAR in that order regardless of what I actually input. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rewriting your snippet to use Str1 instead of X. This will ensure you're comparing a string type to a another string type.

```
:Input Str1

:If Str1="APPLE"
:Then
:Disp "BANANA"
:End

:If Str1="LEMON"
:Then
:Disp "LIME"
:End

:If Str1="PEACH"
:Then
:Disp "PEAR"
:End
```

Comment: Hello, when I try this, I get ERR:DATA TYPE

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, but it is using unnecessary Then/End statements and end quotes for a total of 18 bytes extra. I'd recommend this code which is more similar to your original:

```
Input Str1
If Str1="APPLE
Disp "BANANA
If Str1="LEMON
Disp "LIME
If Str1="PEACH
Disp "PEAR
```

Assuming the above code is an entire program, it can be shortened to:

```
Input Str1
If Str1="APPLE    <-- you can remove this line if you know there will be no invalid input
"BANANA
If Str1="LEMON
"LIME
If Str1="PEACH
"PEAR
Ans
```